# How can i log (keep track of) a change

Tags: java, loops

I want to program a loop to run for 5 seconds that resets back to 0 if any of the conditional statements are true. This part, however, I have completed, the only thing now is that I want to be able to keep track of how many times each conditional statement is used, e.g. (left 1, right 1, left 2, left 3, forward 1, right 2)

I want to be able to log a single variable for each conditional statement that increases each time that particular statement is used in the loop.

The problem I keep encountering is because the values are within a while loop I am unable to only iterate once for each true condition.

```
while the loop runs

  if this == true

    log once

  else if == true

    log once

  else if  == true

    log once

  else if  == true 

    log once

  # end if/else
# end while
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. It would help to post some actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say, if you want to keep it simple, you can declare `int` values for each thing you want to keep track of.

You can say:

```
int left = 0;
int right = 0;
int forward = 0;
```

And increment them in the loops respectively.

You can also use an enumerator, but for this, it looks like just `ints` would be good.